# Renaming folder gives strange error

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, folder, rename

Renaming a folder in a Modern Team Site Collection gives us this error. It happens to a user who has full control of the site but is in an O365 Group.

> An entry without a type name was found.

Does anyone know what it means or how I can resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I need to collect the following information to further troubleshoot the issue:

How do you rename the folder? manually or using flow or using code?

Whether you can Rename another folder in the same library.

Whether you can Rename another folder in the other library.

Whether other user can rename the folder.

Comment: It is only happening to the user and I cannot recreate it. I will get back with answers